# WPF - Error after using Int32.Parse

Tags: wpf, xaml

After using `Int32.Parse` in `ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule` class I get an error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

When I add to XAML:

```
<local:ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule x:Name="Number" ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
```

Program is Running normaly and this walidation work properly. In design window I haven't any content, only `FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` message. Everything is allright when I comment this line in XAML.

```
class ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            int str = -1;
              str = Int32.Parse(value as string);
            if (str > 0)
            {
                if (str > 0)
                    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false, "please fill required field");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show more code?  We don't know what `ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule` is, etc.

Comment: @Jeff-Meadows I add this class.

Comment: Are you sure value is of type string? What is the content of value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `int32.TryParse`

```
class ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int str;
        if (Int32.TryParse(value as string, out str))
        {
            if (str > 0)
                return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(false, "please fill required field");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could catch `FormatException` and return your false validation result.

```
class ComboBoxNotEmptyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int str = -1;
        try
        {
            str = Int32.Parse(value as string);
            if (str > 0)
            {
                if (str > 0)
                    return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false, "please fill required field");
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "please fill required field");
        }
    }
}
```